# jQuery.datepicker is undefined on second call

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

**My goal**

I'm trying to exclude certain dates from my datepicker by making them unclickable.

Stack overflow tought me to do so the following way: [Example code I used (by stack overflow)](http://jsfiddle.net/jnthb29s/3/)

**My code:**

```
var myDates = ["05-05-2019","06-05-2019","07-05-2019"]

$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yyyy', date);
        return [ myDates.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
    }
});
```

I followed the example code and the following error keeps popping up regardless of my actions trying to solve the issue:

> TypeError: jQuery.datepicker is undefined

**Expected output:**

The datepicker shows up and proceeds to block the three days I specified in my `myDates`.

**Additional information:**

The datepicker already shows up. So, datepicker should be working properly. The part where I think it must go wrong should be on this line: `jQuery.datepicker.formatDate`.

I've searched all over the web and didn't seem to find anyone with the same issue as me. If you could help me finding out where it goes wrong that would be very much appreciated. I know the question may sound simple. I'm baffled on why this is not working.

Comment: Are you sure that the datepicker js is properly linked?

Comment: @ZainulAbideen on the first call datepicker works so I think so yes

Comment: I have no clue what's the issue here, in the 'Example code I used' example it works without any issue...

Comment: @golddragon007 Well, thats kind of why I'm so baffled. There are other ways but they take much more code

Comment: try `$.datepicker.formatDate` instead of `jQuery.datepicker.formatDate`

Comment: @Roy `TypeError: $.datepicker is undefined` unfortunately

Comment: @Marty it looks like "Example code I used" is working fine.

Comment: @MayankPatel thats why I'm so confused on why it's not working in my project

Comment: maybe you're missing the `jquery-ui.min.js`?

Comment: What order did you include your scripts? it should be:
1. `jquery`  2.`jquery-ui`

Comment: @Roy I've imported jquery-ui I'm sure

Comment: The best option is edit the post and add all the code you have.

Comment: @Roy I appriciate you! But I dont think it's possible since im working on a giant project. I do have `'/js/jquery-ui.custom.min'` in my default file

Comment: @Marty How you call your code? When it will be executed?

Comment: @golddragon007 I call it underneath `html` in between `<script>` tags

Comment: Eeeeh I'm not sure that's good, put it into head or body and use `$(window).load()` or `$(document).ready()`. Or at least inside the body end without any additional stuff.

Comment: If you dont show us the problem insitu, we can't help you, fiddle is working...

Comment: @golddragon007 It is I'm sorry my foult and its in the `$(document).ready(function ()`

Comment: @Marty I guess you have a script conflict. Because even with the worst code it works. So I assume, you have a loaded script (3rd party or custom) which mess up this datepicker (or you reload somewhy in a point of the time the jquery library). Try to remove the scripts one-by-one, and when it's suddenly starts working, that script is the problem. I had similar issue with colorbox, the DOM was processed but didn't worked... Just make sure you clear the cache (inc. browsers or use hard refresh) every time when you try, to make sure you don't load a previous version of the site.

Comment: @golddragon007 I think thats the issue. Pretty its my bootstrap. Ill find a way to work around it. Thanks my guy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution exists of working around the issue.

I put all my `array` data in an `object` and did this:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var day = date.getDate();
        var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
        var year = date.getFullYear();
        var fullDate = day + '-' + month + '-' + year;
        var bDisable = dates.indexOf(fullDate);
        if (bDisable >= 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```